# General solution for partial equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $f(u,v), g(u,v)$ be two smooth functions of two variables.

I'm trying to find a general solution to this partial equition:
$$f_u\cdot g_v-f_v\cdot g_u=Const. $$

($f_u = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}$)

Comment: Do you mean $f_u = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ instead?

Comment: Yes. I didn't found this sign.